# API credentials are incorrect with paypal_permissions gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using https://github.com/moshbit/paypal_permissions for get seller permissions on my app.

All methods is working fine but when I try with methods `get_basic_personal_data` and `get_advanced_personal_data` I get this response in my log:

```
{:raw_response=>"responseEnvelope.timestamp=2012-09-27T04%3A36%3A17.904-07%3A00&response
Envelope.ack=Failure&responseEnvelope.correlationId=3baaaa7435436&responseEnvelope.build
=2210301&error(0).errorId=520003&error(0).domain=PLATFORM&error
(0).subdomain=Application&error(0).severity=Error&error(0).category=Application&error
(0).message=Authentication+failed.+API+credentials+are+incorrect.", :errors=>
[{:parameters=>[], :error_id=>"520003", :domain=>"PLATFORM", :subdomain=>"Application",
 :severity=>"Error", :category=>"Application", :message=>"Authentication failed. API
 credentials are incorrect."}], :personal_data=>{},
:timestamp=>"2012-09-27T04:36:17.904-07:00", :ack=>"Failure", :correlation_id=>"3baaaa7435436"}
```

You can see these method on https://github.com/moshbit/paypal_permissions/blob/master/examples/app/controllers/merchants_controller.rb

These are my 3 methods in my `users_controller.rb` + the method `get_basic_personal_data` in the end:

```
def request_permissions_callback
    callback_url = URI.encode(response_permissions_callback_user_url(current_user))
    permissions = 'REFUND, ACCESS_BASIC_PERSONAL_DATA'
    paypal_response = ::PAYPAL_PERMISSIONS_GATEWAY.request_permissions callback_url, permissions
    if paypal_response[:ack] == 'Success'
      session[:id] = current_user.id
      request_token = paypal_response[:token]
      session[:request_token] = request_token
      url = ::PAYPAL_PERMISSIONS_GATEWAY.redirect_user_to_paypal_url(request_token)
      redirect_to url
    else
      #render :text => paypal_response.inspect
      # handle error
      format.html { redirect_to requirements_to_sell_user_path(current_user), alert: t(".permissions_wrong") }
    end
end

def response_permissions_callback
  session[:request_token_verifier] = params[:verification_code]
  get_access_token
  logger.info get_basic_personal_data(current_user).inspect
  p get_basic_personal_data(current_user).inspect
  respond_to do |format|
    if get_access_token == true
     format.html { redirect_to requirements_to_sell_user_path(current_user), notice: t(".refund_permissions_success") }
    elsif get_access_token == false
     format.html { redirect_to requirements_to_sell_user_path(current_user), alert: t(".refund_permissions_wrong") }
    end 
  end
end


def get_access_token
    request_token = session[:request_token]
    verifier = session[:request_token_verifier]
    paypal_response = ::PAYPAL_PERMISSIONS_GATEWAY.get_access_token request_token, verifier
    if paypal_response[:ack] == 'Success'
      current_user.update_attributes({
        :ppp_access_token => paypal_response[:token],
        :ppp_access_token_verifier => paypal_response[:token_secret],
      })
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
end

def get_basic_personal_data(current_user)
    access_token = current_user.ppp_access_token
    verifier = current_user.ppp_access_token_verifier
    ::PAYPAL_PERMISSIONS_GATEWAY.get_basic_personal_data(access_token, verifier)
 end
```

- The `request_permissions_callback` (make a request to paypal and the user is redirected to paypal permissions page.)
- The `response_permissions_callback` received response from paypal and call to `get_access_token` for update the data on my mongodb database.

I get error log when the seller return from paypal permissions account with

`logger.info get_basic_personal_data(current_user).inspect`

After `get_access_token` is fired I can see in my database the correct token for after use on `get_basic_personal_data` method:

```
ppp_access_token: "ZlM-jt4LQUxQZDozxkH29I53QyXShtziJIbPlCk3m35i65iLiqVf7w", ppp_access_token_verifier: "wJd3uuP5ymyWAqiUf2qaVCPTMsk"
```

**Why I get this error in this method if the others 3 methods is working fine and api credentials are correct?, Where is the error?**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Mark for his help :D.

The error was on my `development.rb` file.

you can comment or remove `ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test` line and now is working fine.

```
Myapp::Application.configure do
  config.after_initialize do
    #ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
    permissions_options = {
     :login => 'myapp_api1.gmail.com',
     :password => 'mypassword',
     :signature => 'mysignature',
     :app_id => 'APP-80W284485P519543T',  # This is the app_id for all PayPal Permissions Service sandbox test
     apps
    }
    ::PAYPAL_PERMISSIONS_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalPermissionsGateway.new(permissions_options)
  end
end
```

Thank you very much!